# Is Tor Illegal in Italy?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I'm new into Tor world. Can I use Tor (go in deep web and visit it without buy or talk nowhere) in Italy without have risk to go in police problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the Tor network you do not break any law in Italy. Using Tor is legal in Italy.

Comment: http://www.cryptolaw.org/cls2.htm#it

Comment: @canonizingironize: "There is a law that demands accessibility of encrypted records for the treasury". Meaning?  "The people" must have reasonable access, or the treasury must have access?

Comment: [IANAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL).